# Shell script split du -sh * result

Tags: shell, awk, du

I am a beginner of shell script.

Today I want to create a shell script for checking disk usage,
and I using `du -sh *|grep [MG]|sort -r` to log the result like this:

```
space=$(du -sh *|grep [MG]|sort -r)
for file in $space
do 
    echo $file
done

====== result:
10G
fileA
50M
fileB
```

But I want to get the result as an object like:

```
{
"fileA": "10G",
"fileB": "50M"
}
```

How can I use `awk` or other command to reorganize the result?

Comment: Please check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211716/store-output-diskspace-df-h-json

Comment: The [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) coupled with the [quoting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) beg the question, why do you think you need a loop over the output in the first place?

Comment: @Yuk_dev : What do you mean by _result as an object_? Shell has no objects, only strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## From `du` to json

Given `du`'s  output format ...

```
14M     someFile
6.6M    anotherFile
576K    yetAnotherFile
0       MyEmptyFile
```

... you can use `sed` to convert into json:

<sub>Here we assume that you don't have to quote special symbols in the file names, for instance `"`. You can quote them by inserting sed commands like `s/"/\\"/g`. If you also have to deal with linebreaks inside filenames check out `du -0` and `sed -z`.</sub>

```
... | sed -E '1i {
s/(.*)\t(.*)/"\2": "\1",/
$s/,$//
$a }'
```

## Filtering `du`'s output

Please note that `du -sh *| grep [MG] | sort -r` may not do what you expect. With the example files from above you would get

```
6.6M    anotherFile
14M     someFile
0       MyEmptyFile
```

- I assume you want to show only files with sizes > 1MB and < 1TB. However, `grep [MG]` also selects files which contain `M` or `G` in their name. If the current directory contains a file named just `M` or `G` you might even end up with just `grep M` or `grep G` as the unquoted `[MG]` is a glob (like `*`) that can be expanded by bash.
  Use `grep '^[0-9.]*[MG]'` to safely select files with sizes specified in `MB` and `GB`.
- With `sort -r` you probably want to sort by file size. But this does not work because `sort -r` sorts alphabetically, not numerically (i.e. `9` > `11`). But even with numerical sort you would end up with the wrong order, as the suffixes `M` and `G` are not interpreted (i.e. `2M` > `1G`).
  Use `sort -hr` to sort by file sizes.

## Putting everything together

```
du -sh * | grep '^[0-9.]*[MG]' | sort -hr | sed -E '1i {
s/(.*)\t(.*)/"\2": "\1",/
$s/,$//
$a }'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and using sed to convert the result, I will study more about when should I use the method "sed" and "awk"

Comment: My rule of thumb is: Use `sed` if you want to modify **strings** in short or rather unstructured lines and (this is the most important part!) the result for each line is **independet from the other lines**. Use `awk` **for everything else** (e.g. for numbers, or tables with many columns, or data for which you have to consider more than one line at a time).

Comment: In my [`awk` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62532875/548225), I made sure that I produce correct json strong. This `sed` solution doesn't produce valid json format as it doesn't have trailing comma.

Comment: @anubhava Oh right, that's one thing I forgot. Thank you for the information. I guess, OP should accept your answer instead.

Comment: I updated my answer. Commas are now inserted between the entries (but not after the last entry, as required by json).

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```
du -sh * |
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN{ print "{" }
$1 ~ /[GM]$/ {printf "%s\"%s\": \"%s\"", (++n>1?",\n":""), $2, $1}
END{ print "\n}" }'
```

This assumes you don't have tab character in your filenames.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you also provide a great solution to me!

Answer (score 0):

This is with GNU awk

```sh
du -sh * |
grep -E '^[0-9.]+[MG]' |

# sort -h for human numeric sort that understands M and G suffixes
sort -hr |

awk -F'\t' '
BEGIN { print "{" }

# print trailing comma for previous line
NR > 1 { print "," }

{ printf "\"" $2 "\": \"" $1 "\"" }

END { print "\n}" }
'
```